# How to Generate Ranked Table from Employee Data in JavaScript? (Besson rank)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, ranking

I have an array of employee data in JavaScript, and I have been trying to generate a ranked table based on specific criteria. The employee data includes the following fields: name, workEthic, loanAmount, discipline, and workExperience.

I want to create a ranked table where the employees are ranked based on each criterion, and if there are ties, the average rank should be calculated. The desired table format should include the following columns: No, Name, workEthic, loanAmount, discipline, and workExperience.

I have attempted to write the code to calculate the rankings and generate the table, but I haven't been successful. I'm not sure how to handle ties and calculate the average rank. Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
// Employee data
const employees = [
  {
    name: 'Budi',
    workEthic: 60,
    loanAmount: 50,
    discipline: 100,
    workExperience: 40
  },
  {
    name: 'Andi',
    workEthic: 80,
    loanAmount: 50,
    discipline: 80,
    workExperience: 40
  },
  {
    name: 'Rudi',
    workEthic: 100,
    loanAmount: 50,
    discipline: 80,
    workExperience: 40
  }
];

// 1. Create a ranking object
const rankings = {
  workEthic: [],
  loanAmount: [],
  discipline: [],
  workExperience: []
};

// 2. Calculate employee rankings
employees.forEach(employee => {
  rankings.workEthic.push({ name: employee.name, value: employee.workEthic });
  rankings.loanAmount.push({ name: employee.name, value: employee.loanAmount });
  rankings.discipline.push({ name: employee.name, value: employee.discipline });
  rankings.workExperience.push({ name: employee.name, value: employee.workExperience });
});

// 3. Sort employee rankings
for (const criteria in rankings) {
  rankings[criteria].sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value); // Sort in descending order based on value

  // Calculate average rankings if there are equal values
  let rank = 1;
  let totalRank = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < rankings[criteria].length; i++) {
    const currentEmployee = rankings[criteria][i];
    const nextEmployee = rankings[criteria][i + 1];

    if (nextEmployee && currentEmployee.value === nextEmployee.value) {
      rank++;
      totalRank += rank;
    } else {
      if (rank > 1) {
        const averageRank = totalRank / rank;
        currentEmployee.rank = averageRank;
        rank = 1;
        totalRank = 1;
      } else {
        currentEmployee.rank = rank;
      }
    }
  }
}

// 4. Display the ranking results
for (const criteria in rankings) {
  console.log(`\nRanking based on ${criteria}:`);
  rankings[criteria].forEach((employee, index) => {
    console.log(`Rank ${index + 1}: ${employee.name}`);
    if (employee.rank) {
      console.log(`Average Rank: ${employee.rank}`);
    }
  });
}
```

Here is the desired table format:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dJil.png)

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could assist me with the JavaScript code to generate the ranked table based on the given employee data. I'm specifically looking for guidance on how to handle ties and calculate the average rank. Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: i tried everything but failed when it comes to the average rank, it's so difficult for me

Answer (score 0):

```
// Employee data
const employees = [
  {
    name: 'Budi',
    workEthic: 60,
    loanAmount: 50,
    discipline: 100,
    workExperience: 40
  },
  {
    name: 'Andi',
    workEthic: 80,
    loanAmount: 50,
    discipline: 80,
    workExperience: 40
  },
  {
    name: 'Rudi',
    workEthic: 100,
    loanAmount: 50,
    discipline: 80,
    workExperience: 40
  }
];

// 1. Create a ranking object
const rankings = {
  workEthic: [],
  loanAmount: [],
  discipline: [],
  workExperience: []
};

// 2. Calculate employee rankings
employees.forEach(employee => {
  Object.entries(employee).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (key !== 'name') {
      rankings[key].push({ name: employee.name, value: value });
    }
  });
});

// 3. Sort employee rankings
for (const criteria in rankings) {
  rankings[criteria].sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value); // Sort in descending order based on value

  // Calculate average rankings if there are equal values
  let rank = 1;
  let totalRank = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < rankings[criteria].length; i++) {
    const currentEmployee = rankings[criteria][i];
    const nextEmployee = rankings[criteria][i + 1];

    if (nextEmployee && currentEmployee.value === nextEmployee.value) {
      rank++;
      totalRank += rank;
    } else {
      if (rank > 1) {
        const averageRank = totalRank / rank;
        currentEmployee.rank = averageRank;
        rank = 1;
        totalRank = 1;
      } else {
        currentEmployee.rank = rank;
      }
    }
  }
}

// 4. Generate the ranked table
const table = document.createElement('table');
const thead = document.createElement('thead');
const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

// Create table headers
const headers = ['No', 'Name', 'workEthic', 'loanAmount', 'discipline', 'workExperience'];
const trHeader = document.createElement('tr');
headers.forEach(header => {
  const th = document.createElement('th');
  th.textContent = header;
  trHeader.appendChild(th);
});
thead.appendChild(trHeader);
table.appendChild(thead);

// Create table rows
let rankNo = 1;
for (const criteria in rankings) {
  rankings[criteria].forEach((employee, index) => {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    const tdNo = document.createElement('td');
    tdNo.textContent = rankNo;
    tr.appendChild(tdNo);

    const tdName = document.createElement('td');
    tdName.textContent = employee.name;
    tr.appendChild(tdName);

    const tdValue = document.createElement('td');
    tdValue.textContent = employee.value;
    tr.appendChild(tdValue);

    tbody.appendChild(tr);
    rankNo++;
  });
}

table.appendChild(tbody);
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

**The updated code**
It will generate an HTML table with the ranked employee data based on the given criteria. Each employee's rank is calculated and displayed in the "No" column, and their corresponding values are shown in the respective columns.

Hope this may help!!

Comment: actually the algorithm is still incorrent, i dont really need it to be display as a table as long as the calculation for the rank is right. what i mean table is consolelog table, maybe its array table idk

Comment: Please describe briefly. what exactly do you need?